# ComboBox.ItemTemplate for multiple controls

Tags: silverlight, xaml, combobox, datatemplate, itemtemplate

I have 10 ComboBox controls that will use the same item template (an Image and a Textblock), and the same items, so I want to define this template on a more global scale (page level). This is what I've done so far:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
     <DataTemplate x:Name="CBItem">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"></Image>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextLabel}"></TextBlock>
          </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to use this resource in the following 10 ComboBox controls. I've tried something like

```
        <ComboBox Height="25">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="{StaticResource CBItem}"></DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

But it doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<ComboBox Height="25" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CBItem}"/>
```

Or better, also create a style:

```
<Style x:Key="cmbStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CBItem}" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
</Style>
```

and then:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource cmbStyle}"/>
```

Or, if all the Comboboxes in the page should have this style:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CBItem}" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
</Style>
```

and then:

```
<ComboBox />
```